# CoreServices.framework missing in iOS 4 sdk

Tags: iphone, ios4

I wanted to use CFHttpMessage and CFHttpRequest types in my application. I used it and found from documentation that to use it I will have to include CoreServices.framework in my application. When I tried to add that framework to my application, it was no there in the list of framework. I also checked the frameworks directory in finder but its not there. So its problem in the iOS sdk. I am not able to use the CFHttpMessage and CFHttpRequest types in my application, because it can not find the framework thats why it gives the linking error. At installation time of iOS sdk I chosen all the options and made full installation. So from where can I bring the CoreServices.framework in my application.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn' exist: http://markmail.org/message/ib7kdwfpvoovomng